# How to catch USB interrput from non-HID device in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows, camera, usb, sniffing

I’ve got a USB camera (Dentamerica Cammy) (it is NOT identified as  HID device) with a button and the application (named vixwin) that should react to this button and make a picture.

he problem is that it doesn’t react. The device driver is very old and is no longer supported by manufacturer. The only application that reacts when I press the button is the native camera program from the CD.

I’ve tried to use wireshark to sniff usb packets and see, what does the camera do when I press the button. When I start the “capture” function in the app It shows a window with a video stream and after that every time I press the button the camera generates a usb interrupt transfer so the app makes a picture. The camera does not send usb interrupt transfers to the host when video stream is not working.

So my idea was to make a simple windows service that can listen usb traffic and if it sees a usb interrupt from the camera – it should send a hotkey to vixwin app. (Vixwin also uses a video stream from the camera, so I hope it should work fine).

Please tell me how can I scan usb traffic (in parallel mode, like wireshark does) without taking control of it and catch that usb interrupt transfer (hopefully using C#)? Giving a similar code example could be perfect. Or maybe you can advise other solution?

p.s. the host uses Windows 7 and cannot be upgraded to higher windows versions at a moment.

[Wireshark interrupt screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0lRe.jpg)

Comment: This is extremely tiresome to read. Can you add paragraphs by editing in empty lines, so that the text is more logically structured, please?

Comment: i don't know if this can help you, but you should take a look at http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpUSBLib/

Answer (score 0):

in USB protocol the host has to request the interrupt meaning that the host polls the device if it has an interrupt pending
 the windows procedure for this is in https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/dn303348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - *implementing USB interrupt event handler*

alternatively you can use `tshark` , the commandline interface to wireshark or  `USBPcap` to sniff USB in a background process and parse the output (`if`, `FINDSTR`,...) if the interrupt came from your cam

http://www.superuser.com/questions/873896/wireshark-usb-traces-explanations

https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/48789/usbpcap-tutorial

https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/20545/right-interface-to-use-with-tshark-under-windows -  get available capture interfaces

https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/53919/how-can-i-precisely-specify-a-usb-device-to-capture-with-tshark